# Automapper 9 and Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

I am using Automapper 9 and getting Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.  I upgraded from Automapper 2 and I am almost done.  I am not sure why I am getting this error.

```
[InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.]
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IRuntimeMethodInfo method) +0
   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType, Object target) +40
   System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.CreateDelegate() +81
   System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator) +138
   AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.CreateMapperFuncs(MapRequest mapRequest) +76
   AutoMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.<.ctor>b__1() +35
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +304
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +258
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +99
   AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.GetMapperFunc(MapRequest mapRequest) +115
   AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.GetMapperFunc(TypePair types, IMemberMap memberMap) +202
   AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(TSource source) +171
```

**Mapping**

```
  config.CreateMap<Event, EventModel>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Meta, o => o.MapFrom<MetaResolver>())
                .ForMember(d => d.Slug, o => o.Ignore())
                .ForMember(d => d.Logo, o => o.Ignore())
                .ForMember(d => d.CityState, o => o.Ignore())
                .ForMember(d => d.EventVenues, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.EventVenues)).PreserveReferences();
```

**Calling Code**

```
   return Mapper.Map<List<Event>, List<EventModel>>(_eventsRepository.GetMany(includes, @where).OrderByDescending(q => q.StartDate ?? DateTime.MinValue).ToList());
```

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: That would be a little to hard to do with so many models

Comment: Perhaps, but just imagine how rare your error is. If you don't properly isolate the issue, you'll just have to get lucky :)

Comment: True but shouldn’t there be a way on my end to do that?

Comment: Of course there is, it's just extra work. And nobody can do it for you.

Comment: I mean to test within my project to verify this errors location. Maybe download source?

Comment: AM has SourceLink, so just research how you can use that. No need to download the source.

Comment: I added it and can debug shortly in it but cant get any further.  I have never been able to successfully upgrade from automapper 2 to any newer versions because there is always an issue that seems to be so complex.

Comment: It's not complex. You can simply start commenting stuff until you isolate it. But it might take a while, I agree :)

Comment: I have a test case, there is nothing to comment out.  I get into automapper source code and it just errors, cant see debug symbols, etc.

Comment: Make a runnable gist then, as I requested.

Comment: I wish I could but including all 30 sub childs and their child subchilds on the entity framework item, is just ridiculous.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: I did that but I am not sure what I am suppose to do with it.  There has to be better debugging in this.  I have thousands of lines of code.

Comment: That's already a problem. How many properties do you have?

Comment: A ton, this is a national website that maps EF entities to models, and automapper has to have maps for every single one. We have over 150 tables in our database so do the math.

Comment: That's not relevant. The number of properties for one map is relevant. If there are really a hundred for example, the plan would be huge, and that can be a problem. But then you would notice that. It would take up a lot of resources, memory and CPU.

Comment: Thats the point, the entity has sub properties of sub properties, because its an EF property with FK.  It works fine for 2.1.267 and always have.  Replicating this would take a long time and even doing that it may not catch everything.

Comment: Again, that's not relevant for what I'm talking about.

Comment: If you are talking about the plan, I cant even go into it to view the execution plan properties.  It says its not viewable.  I said I didnt know what to do after putting the execution plan in and to view something.